# Subtraction of two sums grouped by asset type?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, like this:

```
|id|   user_id|xact_type|amount|asset_type|
|1 |         1|   Credit|   100|       usd|
|2 |         2|    Debit|   100|       usd|
|3 |         1|   Credit|   100|       eur|
|4 |         2|    Debit|   100|       eur|
|5 |         1|    Debit|    50|       eur|
|6 |         2|   Credit|    50|       eur|
```

I need to sum all amounts which type is Credit and all amounts which type is Debit for **user_id = 1** grouping by asset_type respectively.
And then subtract sum of debits from sum of credits for each asset_type. E.g. For example table and **user_id = 1** it would be:
100 usd (no debits for this asset type)
50 eur (credit - debit, 100 - 50)

```
|user_id|sum|asset_type|
|      1|100|       usd|
|      1| 50|       eur|
```

How can i do this in a single query?

Comment: In MySQL I'd use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SELECT …` with the grouped values, then would perform another SELECT to compute the subtractions. Depending on your environment, you can run more than one query in the same command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id, asset_type,
       sum(case when xact_type = 'Credit' then amount
                when xact_type = 'Debit' then - amount
                else 0
           end) 
from t
group by user_id, asset_type;
```

Comment: that's exactly what i'm looking for. last question is it fast (performance aspect)?

Comment: @zendor_code . . . I don't think there is a faster alternative, unless you have other transaction types and want to filter them out before aggregating.